# Unity: How can I put one object on top of another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I need put my 3D Object dynamicly to platform because 3D Object has a different size.

My code is `_sceneObject.sceneItem.transform.localPosition = _gobletPlatform.localPosition;` but he fixes on it, not on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Collider platformCollider = (_gobletPlatform.GetComponent<Collider>();
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (_gobletPlatform.transform.position.x + platformCollider.bounds.size.x, _gobletPlatform.transform.position.y + platformCollider.bounds.size.y, _gobletPlatform.transform.position.z + platformCollider.bounds.size.z);
_sceneObject.sceneItem.transform.position = pos;
```

Note: I can't test this now. But, I hope it works.

Comment: Does not work. Leaves behind the camera. 3D Object and Platform have one parent

Comment: @user3239481 , Please try this:Collider platformCollider = (_gobletPlatform.GetComponent<Collider>();
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (_sceneObject.sceneItem.transform.position.x, _gobletPlatform.transform.position.y + platformCollider.bounds.size.y, _sceneObject.sceneItem.transform.position.z);
_sceneObject.sceneItem.transform.position = pos;

Comment: Did not help. My platform Y: 0.75, sceneItem: 1.17. Need: sceneItem: 0.84 ~